# How can I create a LINQ statement that does a count of a joined table?

Tags: c#, linq

I have two classes in my Entity Framwork Identity:

```
public partial class AspNetRole
{        
public AspNetRole()
    {
        this.AspNetUsers = new List<AspNetUser>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AspNetUser> AspNetUsers { get; set; }
}

public partial class AspNetUser
{
    public AspNetUser()
    {
        this.AspNetRoles = new List<AspNetRole>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AspNetRole> AspNetRoles { get; set; }

}
```

I was using this LINQ Query to get the roleId and the users that have
that roleId:

```
var user1 = await db.AspNetRoles
            .Include(u => u.AspNetUsers)
            .Select(u => new RoleGetDTO
            {
                RoleId = u.Id,
                Name = u.Name,
                Users = u.AspNetUsers.Select(y => new RoleGetDTO.User
                {
                    UserId = y.Id,
                    Name = y.UserName
                }).ToList()
            })
            .ToListAsync();
```

Can someone help me. Now instead of showing a collection of the users I would just like to 
get a count of the users in the role.

Here's my RoleDTO now:

```
    public class RoleGetDTO
    {
        public int RoleId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }

        public class User
        {
            public int UserId { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

I would like to change it to:

```
    public class RoleGetDTO
    {
        public int RoleId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int UserCount { get; set; }
    }
```

I hope my question makes sense and hope someone can show me how I can change the LINQ so that now it populates the UserCount integer for each RoleId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call the [`Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb338038%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method instead:

```
var user1 = await db.AspNetRoles
            .Include(u => u.AspNetUsers)
            .Select(u => new RoleGetDTO
            {
                RoleId = u.Id,
                Name = u.Name,
                UserCount = u.AspNetUsers.Count()
            })
            .ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var user1 = await db.AspNetRoles
        .Include(u => u.AspNetUsers)
        .Select(u => new RoleGetDTO
        {
            RoleId = u.Id,
            Name = u.Name,
            UsersCount = u.AspNetUsers.Count()
        })
        .ToListAsync();
```